# Adding new strings to localizable strings file in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, localizable.strings

I know how to generate my `Localizable.strings` file from all the source (*.m) files of the project (if anyone wonders, see [this](http://www.gargoylesoft.com/blog/2011/02/localizable-strings/)).

Then, since I'm using XCode 4, I add new languages in the `Identity` tab of the right panel. Then I successfully edit the files for the new languages. So far, so good.

I also use some localizable strings whose keys are not strings literals, but variables, so I have to append them manually to the end of each file. I'm fine with that, no problem.

But now I'm making some changes in my code, and new localized strings are appearing. Is there a way to add those new strings to the Localizable.strings file (ideally for every language), **without loosing** the previous translated strings?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and found a nice little python script to do the job ! As the source is no longer available, take a look at this blog post : http://www.stevestreeting.com/2010/05/18/os-x-localisation-incremental-genstrings-and-utf-8-files/, which basically do the same
Hope that helps !

Comment: Thank you @nicolasthenoz, great job!! I'll test it later but this seems to be exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple app called [Localizable Strings Merge](http://itunes.apple.com/app/localizable-strings-merge/id475333727?mt=12), available on the Mac App Store. Does one thing and does it well. A true time saver.